Want to pursue Master's in AI from a premier university-Master's or bachelor's in Computer Science to make up for poor GPA in first bachelors
I work in supply chain IT with over 15 yrs of experience. I built my career in ERP implementation with specialization in supply chain with roles in IT and in business, but without any degree in computer science. I have a bachelor's in electrical engineering. My estimated overall GPA is 2.52 (62% from India where scores are in %)
I also have a master's in business administration from a university in India with a slightly better GPA of 2.64
I am a senior manager and fancy my chances to become a director as the next step in my career.I am strongly motivated to get the master's degree from a reputed university now.
I would like to pursue an online master's in computer science from a premier institute like Stanford and their posted cut off is 3.0 to apply.
This brings me to my question. Should I get a second bachelor's in computer science from any university that admits me to improve my GPA and then apply for the program I really want? or should I just get a second master's that admits me with my GPA and then apply for the program I want? I am told universities look at GPA in bachelor's degree and not master's GPA.
Is this idea even practical? I have the bandwidth to execute on this idea. I just want to understand will it work (of course assumption is I really improve my GPA. I can make this assumption since my poor GPA is a reflection of my negligence during my college days rather than lack of aptitude)

What is your motivation for ‘pursuing an online master's in computer science from a premier institute like Stanford’? Will that lead to a better chance at successfully landing the director position? I dread suggesting it, but maybe an MBA is a better fit?

"I am a senior manager and fancy my chances to become a director as the next step in my career."  Is the implication that you need an advanced degree to become a director correct??

What's ERP? ...

@AzorAhai-him-: Likely enterprise resource planning.

An admissons committee looking at an applicant with 15 years of industrial experience is likely to pay little attention to undergraduate grades. They will want to know what you did in your job and look for your explanation of why you have decided to apply, what you expect to get from their program, and what you might contribute. I don't think a second Bachelor's degree would make much difference to them.
As @Aruralreader notes, think hard about why you want this degree. Then compose a strong cover letter for your application.
